# This GPA Calculator won't show the GPA Point results after entering Letter Grades

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to convert letter grades to GPA Points. I have the form and the button to calculate the GPA points from the letter grades but every time that I enter the grades and select the "calculate" button, nothing happens, the grades that I just entered disappear. I am not sure how to get this to show up on the screen. Any suggestions on how to

```js
 <script>
 var letterToNumber = {
  A: 4.0,
  B: 3.0,
  C: 2.0,
  D: 1.0
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value;
  var input5 = document.getElementById('input5').value;
  var input6 = document.getElementById('input6').value;
  var input7 = document.getElementById('input7').value;
  
  input1 = letterToNumber[input1];
  input2 = letterToNumber[input2];
  input3 = letterToNumber[input3];
  input4 = letterToNumber[input4];
  input5 = letterToNumber[input5];
  input6 = letterToNumber[input6];
  input7 = letterToNumber[input7];
  console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7);
});

 </script>
```

```css
<style>

body {background-color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000}
h1 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h2 {background-color: #FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h3 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center}
img {display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;}
    list-style-type: none;}
    
.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav a {
display: block;
color: ;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:
hover {
background-color:black;
}
.active {
background-color:white;
color:#E6E6FA;}

table {width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px black double}
caption {font-size: 2em;
         font-weight: bold;}
thead {background-color: White;}
tbody {border: 2px black double;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      font-size: .90em}
tbody td {border-bottom: 1px black double;
         padding-left: 25 px;}
td {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
th {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
tfoot {background-color: #FFDF00;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;}
      
      /* the styles for the elements */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html {
 background-color: white;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #FFDF00;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
nav a:focus, nav a:hover, article a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

/* the styles for the reflection */
header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FFDF00;
 padding: 1.5em 0;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
}
header h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
}
header h2 {
 font-style: italic;
}
header img {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 30px;
}
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFDF00;
}

main {
 clear: left;
 padding: 0 20px 20px;
 width: 525px;
 float: right;
}
main h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
main h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
main p {
 padding-bottom: .5em;
}
main blockquote {
 padding: 0 2em;
 font-style: italic;
}
main ul {
   list-style-type: none
 padding: 0 0 1.5em 1.25em;
}
main li {
 padding-bottom: .35em;
}


aside {
 width: 215px;
 float: right;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
aside h1 {
 color: #800000;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
aside h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
aside img {
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}
/* the styles for the navigation list */
#nav_list ul { 
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
#nav_list li { 
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: .5em;
 border: 2px double black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #FFDF00;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% center;
  
}
#nav_list li a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .5em 0 .5em 1em;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">

<title>Homeroom GPA Calculatiion: Step 2</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
 <script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 

 
</head>
  <!-- Nav -->
   <nav>
    <ul class="links">
     <li><a href="hayes_java_project.html">Home: GPA Calculation Tutorial</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_why.html"> Why Calculate your GPA?</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_1.html">Step 1: Document Your Grades</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_2.html">Step 2: Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_3.html">Step 3: Average GPA Point Total to Get GPA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_4.html">Step 4: Submit GPA for Teachers</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

 
 
 
 <h1>HHS Homeroom GPA Calculation: Step 2</h1>
 <h2>Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</h2>
 <br>
 <p>When calculating your GPA, HHS uses a conversion scale to get GPA points from the percentages in each class. Enter your percentage to see what the GPA points for that particular percentage. Next to the percentage on your paper, write down the GPA points that each class currently has. See example if you are having trouble.</p>
<br>
 <body>
            <h1>Enter Your Grades Below</h1>
            <form name="form" id="form">
                <br>
                Class 1: <input id="input1" type="text" /><br />
    Class 2: <input id="input2" type="text" /><br />
    Class 3: <input id="input3" type="text" /><br />
    Class 4: <input id="input4" type="text" /><br />
    Class 5: <input id="input5" type="text" /><br />
    Class 6: <input id="input6" type="text" /><br />
    Class 7: <input id="input7" type="text" /><br />
    <button>Calculate</button>
            </form>
            <div id="div">
            </div>
        </body>

<br>

    <footer><small><i>Page created by Samantha Hayes.<br>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 <br>
        Please <a href="mailto:shayes@cpsk12.org">e-mail</a> me with any questions.<br>
        Last updated on December 2018. </i></small>
        </footer>
    <p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have your content before or after the `<body>` tag. Also, you're not doing anything to stop the submission of your form. A button's default type is submit. Change your `<button>Calculate</button>` to `<button type="button">Calculate</button>`

Comment: Thank you! I have changed the <button>Calculate</button> to <button type="button">Calculate</button> and the <body> tag's location. However, there is still no results showing after entering letter grades...how can I get that to show up?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this:**

```js
var letterToNumber = [
  ['A', 4.0],
  ['B', 3.0],
  ['C', 2.0],
  ['D', 1.0]
];

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value.toUpperCase();
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value.toUpperCase();
  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value.toUpperCase();
  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value.toUpperCase();
  var input5 = document.getElementById('input5').value.toUpperCase();
  var input6 = document.getElementById('input6').value.toUpperCase();
  var input7 = document.getElementById('input7').value.toUpperCase();
  
  console.clear();
  
  var arrayLength =letterToNumber.length;  
   
  for(var j = 0; j <arrayLength; j++){     
     
     for(var i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++){
    
        if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input1 ) {
        input1 = letterToNumber[i][1];  
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input2 ) {
        input2 = letterToNumber[i][1]; 
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input3 ) {
        input3 = letterToNumber[i][1];
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input4 ) {
        input4 = letterToNumber[i][1];  
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input5 ) {
        input5 = letterToNumber[i][1]; 
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input6 ) {
        input6 = letterToNumber[i][1];  
    }
    
    if( letterToNumber[i][0] == input7 ) {
        input7 = letterToNumber[i][1]; 
    }
    
  }

    }      
  
  console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7);
});
```

```css
body {background-color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000}
h1 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h2 {background-color: #FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h3 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center}
img {display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;}
    list-style-type: none;}
    
.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav a {
display: block;
color: ;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:
hover {
background-color:black;
}
.active {
background-color:white;
color:#E6E6FA;}

table {width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px black double}
caption {font-size: 2em;
         font-weight: bold;}
thead {background-color: White;}
tbody {border: 2px black double;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      font-size: .90em}
tbody td {border-bottom: 1px black double;
         padding-left: 25 px;}
td {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
th {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
tfoot {background-color: #FFDF00;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;}
      
      /* the styles for the elements */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html {
 background-color: white;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #FFDF00;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
nav a:focus, nav a:hover, article a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

/* the styles for the reflection */
header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FFDF00;
 padding: 1.5em 0;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
}
header h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
}
header h2 {
 font-style: italic;
}
header img {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 30px;
}
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFDF00;
}

main {
 clear: left;
 padding: 0 20px 20px;
 width: 525px;
 float: right;
}
main h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
main h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
main p {
 padding-bottom: .5em;
}
main blockquote {
 padding: 0 2em;
 font-style: italic;
}
main ul {
   list-style-type: none
 padding: 0 0 1.5em 1.25em;
}
main li {
 padding-bottom: .35em;
}


aside {
 width: 215px;
 float: right;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
aside h1 {
 color: #800000;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
aside h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
aside img {
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}
/* the styles for the navigation list */
#nav_list ul { 
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
#nav_list li { 
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: .5em;
 border: 2px double black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #FFDF00;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% center;
  
}
#nav_list li a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .5em 0 .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">

<title>Homeroom GPA Calculatiion: Step 2</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hayes_java_project.css">
 <script src="gpa_calculation.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
 

 
</head>
  <!-- Nav -->
   <nav>
    <ul class="links">
     <li><a href="hayes_java_project.html">Home: GPA Calculation Tutorial</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_why.html"> Why Calculate your GPA?</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_1.html">Step 1: Document Your Grades</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_2.html">Step 2: Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_step_3.html">Step 3: Average GPA Point Total to Get GPA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="project_step_4.html">Step 4: Submit GPA for Teachers</a></li>
     <li><a href="project_reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>

 
 
 
 <h1>HHS Homeroom GPA Calculation: Step 2</h1>
 <h2>Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</h2>
 <br>
 <p>When calculating your GPA, HHS uses a conversion scale to get GPA points from the percentages in each class. Enter your percentage to see what the GPA points for that particular percentage. Next to the percentage on your paper, write down the GPA points that each class currently has. See example if you are having trouble.</p>
<br>
 <body>
            <h1>Enter Your Grades Below</h1>
            <form name="form" id="form">
                <br>
                Class 1: <input id="input1" type="text" /><br />
    Class 2: <input id="input2" type="text" /><br />
    Class 3: <input id="input3" type="text" /><br />
    Class 4: <input id="input4" type="text" /><br />
    Class 5: <input id="input5" type="text" /><br />
    Class 6: <input id="input6" type="text" /><br />
    Class 7: <input id="input7" type="text" /><br />
    <button type="button">Calculate</button>
            </form>
            <div id="div">
            </div>
        </body>

<br>

    <footer><small><i>Page created by Samantha Hayes.<br>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 <br>
        Please <a href="mailto:shayes@cpsk12.org">e-mail</a> me with any questions.<br>
        Last updated on December 2018. </i></small>
        </footer>
    <p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you going to explain your code dump or do you expect us to play spot-the-difference?

Comment: The code is still not showing up on my end even though it is showing up on your "Run code snippet." I am not sure why...

Comment: the code is working. Please run code snippet and you will get desired output

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug in your code. I first removed the form since you're using event listener anyways.It also causes your website to redirect that is why there are no outputs. I also put the outputs in the div. Since i noticed that there is an unused div there which i assumed where the outputs would come out. It is probably one of the culprits why you do not have any output shown when submitting.

I used .toUpperCase() since people may enter small letters which would then make the output undefined. It may be unnecessary but please do tell me so i can edit it.

```js
<script>
 var letterToNumber = {
  A: 4.0,
  B: 3.0,
  C: 2.0,
  D: 1.0
};

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value.toUpperCase();
  var input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value.toUpperCase();
  var input3 = document.getElementById('input3').value.toUpperCase();
  var input4 = document.getElementById('input4').value.toUpperCase();
  var input5 = document.getElementById('input5').value.toUpperCase();
  var input6 = document.getElementById('input6').value.toUpperCase();
  var input7 = document.getElementById('input7').value.toUpperCase();
  
  input1 = letterToNumber[input1];
  input2 = letterToNumber[input2];
  input3 = letterToNumber[input3];
  input4 = letterToNumber[input4];
  input5 = letterToNumber[input5];
  input6 = letterToNumber[input6];
  input7 = letterToNumber[input7];
  //didn't removed this cause you may wanna check or i dont know
  console.log(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5, input6, input7);

  //put the output in the div. Since i noticed that there is an unused div there which i assumed where the output would come out
  document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = 'Class 1: ' + input1+'<hr>' + 'Class 2 : ' +input2 +'<hr>'+ 'Class 3: ' +input3+'<hr>'+ 'Class 4: ' +input4+'<hr>' +'Class 5 : ' +input5+'<hr>' + 'Class 6 :' +input6+'<hr>'+'Class 7 :'+input7 ;

});

  </script>
```

```css
body {background-color: #E6E6FA;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000}
h1 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h2 {background-color: #FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color:#000000;
      text-align: center}
h3 {background-color:#FFDF00;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: center}
img {display:inline;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;}
    list-style-type: none;}
    
.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #E6E6FA;
}

.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.topnav a {
display: block;
color: ;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:
hover {
background-color:black;
}
.active {
background-color:white;
color:#E6E6FA;}

table {width: 200px;
      margin: auto;
      border: 1px black double}
caption {font-size: 2em;
         font-weight: bold;}
thead {background-color: White;}
tbody {border: 2px black double;
      font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;
      font-size: .90em}
tbody td {border-bottom: 1px black double;
         padding-left: 25 px;}
td {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
th {text-align: center;
   border: 1px black double}
tfoot {background-color: #FFDF00;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;}
      
      /* the styles for the elements */
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
html {
 background-color: white;
}
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 3px solid #FFDF00;
    background-color: #fffded;
}
nav a:focus, nav a:hover, article a:hover {
 font-style: italic;
}

/* the styles for the reflection */
header {
 border-bottom: 3px solid #FFDF00;
 padding: 1.5em 0;
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(
     30deg, #FFDF00 0%, #fffded 30%, white 50%, #fffded 80%, #FFDF00 100%);
}
header h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
}
header h2 {
 font-style: italic;
}
header img {
 float: left;
 padding: 0 30px;
}
.shadow {
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFDF00;
}

main {
 clear: left;
 padding: 0 20px 20px;
 width: 525px;
 float: right;
}
main h1 {
 color: #FFDF00;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
main h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
main p {
 padding-bottom: .5em;
}
main blockquote {
 padding: 0 2em;
 font-style: italic;
}
main ul {
   list-style-type: none
 padding: 0 0 1.5em 1.25em;
}
main li {
 padding-bottom: .35em;
}


aside {
 width: 215px;
 float: right;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
}
aside h1 {
 color: #800000;
 font-size: 150%;
 padding: .5em 0 .25em;
}
aside h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding-bottom: .25em;
}
aside img {
 padding-bottom: 1em;
}
/* the styles for the navigation list */
#nav_list ul { 
 list-style: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
#nav_list li { 
 width: 200px;
 margin-bottom: .5em;
 border: 2px double black;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #FFDF00;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% center;
  
}
#nav_list li a {
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .5em 0 .5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="en">

<title>Homeroom GPA Calculatiion: Step 2</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>


 
</head>
<!-- Nav -->

 <body>
 <nav>
<ul class="links">
 <li><a href="hayes_java_project.html">Home: GPA Calculation Tutorial</a></li>
 <li><a href="project_why.html"> Why Calculate your GPA?</a></li>
 <li><a href="project_step_1.html">Step 1: Document Your Grades</a></li>
 <li><a href="project_step_2.html">Step 2: Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</a></li>
 <li><a href="project_step_3.html">Step 3: Average GPA Point Total to Get GPA</a></li>
        <li><a href="project_step_4.html">Step 4: Submit GPA for Teachers</a></li>
  <li><a href="project_reflection.html">Reflection</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>

 
 
 
 <h1>HHS Homeroom GPA Calculation: Step 2</h1>
 <h2>Convert Grade Percentages to GPA Points</h2>
 <br>
 <p>When calculating your GPA, HHS uses a conversion scale to get GPA points from the percentages in each class. Enter your percentage to see what the GPA points for that particular percentage. Next to the percentage on your paper, write down the GPA points that each class currently has. See example if you are having trouble.</p>
<br>
    <!-- Removed the form since you're using event listener anyways -->
    <!-- It also causes your website to redirect -->
        <h1>Enter Your Grades Below</h1>
        <br>
        Class 1: <input id="input1" type="text" /><br />
     Class 2: <input id="input2" type="text" /><br />
     Class 3: <input id="input3" type="text" /><br />
  Class 4: <input id="input4" type="text" /><br />
  Class 5: <input id="input5" type="text" /><br />
  Class 6: <input id="input6" type="text" /><br />
  Class 7: <input id="input7" type="text" /><br />
    <button>Calculate</button>
            <div id="div">
            </div>
        </body>

<br>

    <footer><small><i>Page created by Samantha Hayes.<br>
        Copyright &copy; 2018 <br>
        Please <a href="mailto:shayes@cpsk12.org">e-mail</a> me with any questions.<br>
        Last updated on December 2018. </i></small>
        </footer>
    <p>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">
        <img style="border:0;width:88px;height:31px"
            src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss"
            alt="Valid CSS!" />
    </a>
</html>
```

Comment: The results still are not showing up on my screen, even though they are on yours...I am not sure why.

Comment: Have you tried running this code in incognito? maybe your web browser cached